# How to create a rule on QGIS to show only features that have last week as date?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, style

Basically I have a PostGIS layer with a date column.

I only need to show features that have the last week as a value in the date column. How to achieve this?

Unfortunately `now() - 1 week` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Do you mean last week (somewhen between mon and sunday last week) or exactly 7 days past?

Comment: @markgraeflerland exactly 7 days, thought that was the definition of a week

Comment: @Luffydude not necessarily. There are several definitions (any 7 days, Monday-Sunday, or Sunday-Saturday (and other start-end days), plus partial weeks for the 1st or last week of the year). The intended usage in terms of weeks or days is relevant ex: Monday of week 1 is "last week" from Sunday of week 2, but they are more than 7 days apart.

Comment: @Luffydude: If I have a feature with monday in the date column than a feature created last friday would also be a feature created last week, but not neccessarily 7 days ago. That's the reason why I try to find out what your talking about

Comment: Sure guys, make sense. For the purpose of this exercise I would need something like 7 days then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to completly filter out the records, i.e. set a filter at the layer level, you can use the Postgres function to create an interval:

```
"update_date" >= (CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 week')
```

If you want to style/label the records differently, you can use the `age` function to return a timespan between two dates, and the `week` function to extract the number of weeks.

To get result from last week, the rule filter would be:

```
week(age(now(),"update_date"))<=1
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
NOW() - INTERVAL '1 week'
```

instead of

```
now() - 1 week
```